# Using CSS to control Sprite size in the DOM.

Tags: css, css-sprites

Sprites:

I did the following and it looks great but...I do not want the 400px width to display, I want it contained in another img that is 250px. Is there a way (I have tried a lot of methods) to control the sprite size with CSS or do I need a js workaround?

```
.portfolio a .icon1  {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background: url('../images/gate-sprite.png') 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.portfolio a:hover .icon1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background: url('../images/gate-sprite.png') 0 -250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to http://jsfiddle.net that?

Comment: Not another img but a container that restricts the size of the Sprite to 250px.

Answer (score 0):

use the ::before or ::after pseudo element to contain your icon.  That way you set the icon size, and specify the background image for the ::before or ::after element.

Example:

```
.portfolio a .icon1::before  {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background: url('../images/gate-sprite.png') 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

More info on :before and :after here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp